# How can you hide env variables when executing a bash script with -xe?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a bash script that I execute with `/bin/sh -xe script.sh` and I need to capture its output.

The problem is that inside the script I use some ENV variables that I would like to keep them from being displayed in the output.
Is there any way to do this?

Ie. if my script has `touch $MY_ENV_VAR` and MY_ENV_VAR=ok the output of `/bin/sh -xe script.sh` will be `touch ok`.

Is there any way to keep env vars from being replaced in the output of `-x`? So I would just get `+ touch $MY_ENV_VAR` back.

Comment: There is nothing in the POSIX standard which allows this.  All you could do is to `set +o xtrace` then `set -o xtrace` around the code you don't want displayed.  Alternatively, use the `verbose` trace instead of `xtrace`, that's the `-v` option.  By the way, if you are executing with `/bin/sh` then it is not a bash script, it is a `sh` script.

Comment: try to use the `sh -vex` - you will get another lines on the output how the script file is read (`-v`). Hard to read, but sometimes could be useful.

Comment: Thanks. Using `set -ve` instead of `set -xe` seems to do the trick. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @daniels:  why do you need it anyway?

Comment: I'm trying to do something like a CI tool. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html So users define some commands in a yaml file, and I execute them inside docker and show them the output. Sensitive data (like tokens, etc) will be in ENV variables so thay can use it but it should not appear in the log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the POSIX standard which allows this. All you could do is:

```
set +o xtrace       # Switch xtrace off
some hidden code
set -o xtrace       # Switch xtrace back on
```

Alternatively, use the `verbose` trace instead of `xtrace`, that's the `-v` option.

```
/bin/sh -ve script.sh
```

By the way, if you are executing with `/bin/sh` then it is not a `bash` script, it is a `sh` script.